# Model variable inconsistent when passed into view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I don't even know how this is possible but my hidden input values are not what's actually in the model.

This is a partial view that contains a form that gets added to the dom. No other forms or inputs are present in the dom.

Below displays 2 different guids. Added to view the values outside of the debugger. I also see 2 different values debugging before returning the partial as it should.

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ID)
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.StaffID)
```

Now I also have

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.StaffID)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ID)
```

When I inspect the dom, both ID and StaffID contain the StaffID but the model presented to the view have 2 different guids.

Here is the jquery loading the view

```
$(document).on('click', 'span[data-target="#modal-facility-staff-schedule-edit"]', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    WebUI.showPleaseWait();
    var id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "../Management/FacilityStaffScheduleEdit",
        data: { id: id },
        success: function (data) {
            $('body').append(data);
            $('#modal-facility-staff-schedule-edit').modal('toggle');
            WebUI.reloadMasking();
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            WebUI.handleError(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown);
        },
        complete: function () {
            WebUI.hidePleaseWait();
        }
    });
});
```

***Added***

I have added the following to view

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ID)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.StaffID)
<input id="ID" name="ID" type="hidden" value="@Model.ID">
<input id="StaffID" name="StaffID" type="hidden" value="@Model.StaffID">
```

DOM results (HOW?!?!?!?)

```
<input id="ID" name="ID" type="hidden" value="535e8d84-e770-48ee-8e82-56daa63fd603">
<input id="StaffID" name="StaffID" type="hidden" value="535e8d84-e770-48ee-8e82-56daa63fd603">
<input id="ID" name="ID" type="hidden" value="da6d7e8b-3b90-41dc-88d8-98748154cba1">
<input id="StaffID" name="StaffID" type="hidden" value="535e8d84-e770-48ee-8e82-56daa63fd603">
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. Please see this post if anyone else is wondering why.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/simonince/2010/05/05/asp-net-mvcs-html-helpers-render-the-wrong-value/